# open ports on a cisco/linksys wrt54g2 v1.5

Tags: cisco, voip, linksys, port, netgear

Im upgradeing my router from a netgear fvs318

one of the problems im running into is on the old net gear i have opend ports under the "Add Service " for our voip

```
udp 69
tcp 80
tcp 2000
udp 22026-62025
```

but on the new linksys/cisco rotuer i don't see any option to just open a port i see port forwarding (which i dont want because i have more than one phone) and port triggering that i have no idea what that does.

does anyone know either how to allow open ports on this router or how to use port tiggering to allow my phones to work with the ports listed above?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all VoIP boxes do not need any ports opened at all. They just make an outbound connection to the SIP gateway and keep that connection open. What model VoIP box do you have?

Comment: cisco 7960 voip phone

Comment: Who is your SIP Gateway? Are you VPNing it to your work or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but here goes:

Port forwarding is for inbound traffic. If you have multiple phones, they cannot all be on the same inbound port. As far as outbound is concerned, it does not matter unless you are restricting outbound traffic, the wrt54g does not restrict outbound traffic by default.

If you only have a single public IP address, each port can have only a single destination via port forwarding. Pick an internal device / IP address to map it to.